# Cannot Install h2oEnsemble

Tags: r, h2o

Hi hereunder a problem when I try to install h2oEnsemble. I don't know to fix this. PLease help.

My goal here is to run this exemple:

https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-world-2015-training/blob/master/tutorials/ensembles-stacking/ensembles-stacking.R

---

```
> library(devtools)
```

Warning message:
le package ‘devtools’ a été compilé avec la version R 3.1.3

```
> install_github("h2oai/h2o-3/h2o-r/ensemble/h2oEnsemble-package")
```

Downloading GitHub repo h2oai/h2o-3@master
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘RCurl’

```
> install.packages("RCurl")
```

trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.1/RCurl_1.95-4.7.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 2858866 bytes (2.7 Mb)
opened URL
downloaded 2.7 Mb

Warning in install.packages :
  downloaded length 2858866 != reported length 2858866
package ‘RCurl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Djilo\AppData\Local\Temp\RStudioPortableTemp\RtmpmQLJyE\downloaded_packages

```
> install_github("h2oai/h2o-3/h2o-r/ensemble/h2oEnsemble-package")
```

Downloading GitHub repo h2oai/h2o-3@master
Installing h2oEnsemble
Installing 1 packages: RCurl
package ‘RCurl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning: cannot remove prior installation of package ‘RCurl’
"E:/DATAMI~3/R-PORT~1/App/R-PORT~1/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:/Users/Djilo/AppData/Local/Temp/RStudioPortableTemp/RtmpmQLJyE/devtools177417c33da9/h2oai-h2o-3-7eaa37a/h2o-r/ensemble/h2oEnsemble-package" --library="E:/Data  \
  Mining - R/R-Portable/App/R-Portable/library" --install-tests

- installing *source* package 'h2oEnsemble' ...
  ** R
  ** tests
  ** preparing package for lazy loading
  Avis : package 'statmod' was built under R version 3.1.3
  Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called 'RCurl'
  Error : package 'h2o' could not be loaded
  ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'h2oEnsemble'
- removing 'E:/Data Mining - R/R-Portable/App/R-Portable/library/h2oEnsemble'
  Error: Command failed (1)
  In addition: Warning message:
  In download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :
  downloaded length 2858866 != reported length 2858866

Comment: This question was also posted to H2O's google group, and is being discussed here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2ostream/cWRyNyij-D0

Answer (score 0):

This question was [resolved](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2ostream/cWRyNyij-D0) when the user successfully upgraded their H2O installation.  If you don't kill your currently running H2O instance before upgrading, the upgrade may fail.